# Changing the border with of a table with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table generated from Sphinx that has a border of width 1.

```
<table border="1" class="docutils">
```

Can I change the border width to 0 using jQuery/javascript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can. You want to use the [attr() function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like this...

```
$('table.docutils').attr('border', '0');
```

Comment: This is accurate but it is more efficient to create your selector like this `$("table.docutils")`

Comment: or you could just user `$('table.docutils').removeAttr('border')`

Answer (score 3):

I would tend to use the `.css()` function as opposed to `.attr()`... eg:

```
$("table.docutils").css('border', 'none');
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 document.getElementById('myTable').border="0"
<table border="1" class="docutils" id="myTable">
```