# jQuery applying borders on tr doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506295/changing-the-border-with-of-a-table-with-jquery) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812022/how-can-i-change-nested-table-td-border-width-using-jquery), I tried to apply a border on all my `tr` elements. If I do this:

```
$('table').find('tr td').css({'border':'15px solid red'});
```

it works, but I want it on the whole row. Thus I do this:

```
$('table').find('tr').css({'border':'15px solid red'});
```

But it doesn't work!
Background-color and other CSS styles like this work:

```
$('table').find('tr').css({'color':'rgb(100,200,150)'});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another (somewhat) different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040842/add-border-bottom-to-table-row).

```
$('table')
    .css('border-collapse', 'collapse')
    .find('tr')
    .css({'border':'1px solid red'});
```

Comment: Hmm... interesting. And this worked for you?  Good to know for the future, I guess.